# after an ng-repeat I need to isolate and grab one elements 'id'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I want to grab the 'id' of the comment I'm hitting reply to and store that to be used for an Ajax call.   I can currently grab everything else with ng-model, and it doesn't seem I can use the tactic of value="{{this.id}}" in a hidden input to get the value like I would if I were using jquery.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="comments-temp">
<div>
    <ul class="comments" ng-repeat="comment in ctrl.comments">
        <li>
            <div class="comment" id="{{comment.id}}">
                <div class="comment-author">
                    <a href="#" style="background-image: url('assets/img/tmp/agent-1.jpg');"></a>
                </div><!-- /.comment-author -->

                <div class="comment-content">
                    <div class="comment-meta">

                    <div class="comment-meta-author">
                            Posted by <a href="#">admin</a>
                        </div><!-- /.comment-meta-author -->

                        <div class="comment-meta-reply">
                            <a href="#" ng-click="showPanel = true">Reply</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="comment-meta-date">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span>{{comment.dateAdded | date: 'medium'}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.comment -->

                    <div class="comment-body">

                        <div class="comment-item" id="commentTitle">
                            <h6>{{comment.title}}</h6>
                        </div>
                     {{comment.body}}
                    </div><!-- /.comment-body -->
                </div><!-- /.comment-content -->
            </div><!-- /.comment -->

            <panel ng-show="showPanel">
                <div class="comment-create" ng-model="ctrl.reply">
                    <form method="post" action="?">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label>Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.reply.title">
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div><!-- /.col-* -->

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group hidden">
                                    <label>Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.reply.name">
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div><!-- /.col-* -->

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group hidden">
                                    <label>ParentId</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{comment.id}}" ng-model="ctrl.reply.parentId">
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div><!-- /.col-* -->
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-model="ctrl.reply.body"></textarea>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.replyComment(ctrl.reply); showPanel = false;" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Post Reply</button>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group-btn -->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </panel>
            <div style="height:35px"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--comment temp end-->
```

I hope I've been clear.  What I want is this:

```
  <script>
function _replyComment(data){

                vm.commentData = data;
                vm.commentData.blogId = vm.blogId;
                vm.commentData.userId = page.currentUserId;
                vm.commentData.typeId = 1;
                vm.commentData.parentID = //??????? where I want the value the id of the comment I'm replying too 


                console.log(vm.commentData);
                comments.services.insert(data, _onSuccessComment, _onError);// my ajax is in a separate .js file.  it's not important for this demo
 }
  </script>
```

After this I of course have to figure out how to nest the replies in the DOM appropriately.  But this is a question for a different day.  This is where Jquery is easier than angular.

Thanks!

Comment: when you click reply, store the id of that comment in a controller variable, e.g. 'ctrl.reply.id'

Comment: can you be a bit more explicit?  ng-click="ctrl.reply(data); ctrl.reply.id = comment.id"?  I'm sorry, I'm not understanding

Comment: Ahhh.  I understand.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

holtc solved it.  This might be round about, but I created another click that just stored the comment.id.  Then I made a new controller variable and just put it on in my _replyComment function.

```
   vm.getId = _getId;
            vm.pId = null;

            function _getId(data){
                vm.pId = data

                console.log(vm.pId)

            }


            function _replyComment(data){

                vm.commentData = data;
                vm.commentData.blogId = vm.blogId;
                vm.commentData.userId = page.currentUserId;
                vm.commentData.typeId = 1;
                vm.commentData.parentId = vm.pId;
                console.log(vm.commentData);
```